# How can I use Bloomberg's API as a data source on BQuant instead of using BQL for data retrieval?

Tags: bloomberg

I'm interested in leveraging Bloomberg's API as a data source within BQuant instead of relying solely on BQL for data retrieval. BQL seems to have a more limited dataset compared to the API, and I'm curious if it is possible to utilize the API to access a wider range of data,

Comment: Did you ask the help desk?